# Calculating mean of list within dictionary in Python

Tags: python, csv

This is a part of my output. I want to find the average of the list within this dictionary:

```
{'Radial Velocity': {'number': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]}}
```

Comment: I have reworded my question!

Comment: Can you close up the curly braces?

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? Don't just ask "how to code this?" or "please code this for me".

Comment: @Grismar the OP have, it's just been edited out.

Comment: @AnnZen I'm sorry, I don't see what you mean - all I see is a dictionary (with a syntax error), but no attempt at code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62253303/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to solve it using custom code:

```
sumOfNumbers = 0
for number in dictionary['Radial Velocity']['number']:
    sumOfNumbers += number

avg = sumOfNumbers / len(dictionary['Radial Velocity']['number'])
print(avg)
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: in the same manner how would you find the standard deviation and minimum value

Comment: Minimum Value: Use the min() method: `min(dictionary['Radial Velocity']['number']`. Standard Deviation: Check out this website: https://www.codespeedy.com/python-program-to-calculate-the-standard-deviation/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `mean()` from `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
output = {'Radial Velocity': {'number': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]}}
print(np.mean(output['Radial Velocity']['number']))
```

Output:

```
2.1607142857142856
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a [statistics module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) in its standard library. It has, among other useful things, a [`mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) function to which you can pass a list and get the average:

```
from statistics import mean

mean(d['Radial Velocity']['number'])
```